# Database model and extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net, extension-methods, static-classes

In my ASP.NET web site I created new Entity Data Model and connected it with my MsSql database. Now I can use Model.Student class but that class don't have methods. I tried to add extension methods like

```
public static class Functions{
     public static double calculateStudentScore(this Model.Student s){
          //implementation
     }
}
```

When I create new Student and try to call my method, I can't see it, why is so?

For example lets suppose `s` is type of `Student`

```
double score=s.calculateStudentScore();//I can't see my calculateStudentScore method
```

Comment: What value(s) are you trying to calculate..? I don't see any values being passed into the method..

Comment: Have you added `using TheNameSpaceWhereYourExtensionMethodIs;` to the top?

Comment: @Mr.M, to the top of the file where you are using the extension method.  You need to include the namespace, so your code knows to look for extension methods there.

Comment: My extension methods are in the same namespace as class in which I call my methods.

Comment: Maybe this Entity Data Model is problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your EF model is a partial class. While I agree in principle that the extension should be visible, in the meantime, just add a new file, and add the method to the class.

Comment: It's OK now, I forgot static keyword in method declaration.

Thx to all of you!

Comment: That begs an interesting question: to extent or not to extent? Which way is better? faster? more maintainbale?

Comment: Well I done this way because it is easier to maintain. If I change model, there is no problem with my methods :)